# Process CSV file Daily

Tags: php

I currently have a form that I use to upload the data to our DB.  Works great.  I have recently discovered that our system can upload these files to our server which would simplify morning routines and make life easier.   I would like to have the file upload to our server (this is done already) and then process it every morning which I know how to do with a cron.  The issue I'm running into is the script.  Right now it looks for an uploaded file.  How can I make this look for a file on the server and process?

```
<?php

include_once 'connect.php';
$file = 'dpexpected.csv'  // This is a new line I added
if(isset($_POST['rqActivations'])){

    $csvMimes = array('text/x-comma-separated-values', 'text/comma-separated-values', 'application/octet-stream', 'application/vnd.ms-excel', 'application/x-csv', 'text/x-csv', 'text/csv', 'application/csv', 'application/excel', 'application/vnd.msexcel', 'text/plain');

    if(!empty($_FILES['file']['name']) && in_array($_FILES['file']['type'], $csvMimes)){

        if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'])){

            $csvFile = fopen($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], 'r');

            fgetcsv($csvFile);
            fgetcsv($csvFile);
            fgetcsv($csvFile);

            while(($line = fgetcsv($csvFile)) !== FALSE){

                $Invoice_      = $line[0];
                $Invoiced_By   = $line[1];
                $Sold_By       = $line[2];
                $Product_SKU   = $line[3];
                $Sold_On       = $line[4];
                $Customer      = $line[5];
                $Tracking_     = $line[6];
                $Contract_     = $line[7];
                $Product_Name  = $line[8];
                $Selling_Price = $line[9];
                $District      = $line[10];

                $prevQuery = "SELECT ID from dp_expected WHERE Contract_  = '".$line[7]."' AND Tracking_ = '".$line[6]."'";
                $prevResult = $pdo->query($prevQuery);

                if($prevResult->num_rows > 0){

                }elseif($Sold_On != ""){

                  $stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO dp_expected (Invoice_, Invoiced_By, Sold_By, Product_SKU, Sold_On, Customer, Tracking_, Contract_, Product_Name, Selling_Price, District)
                                         VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?,
                                                 ?, ?, ?, ?,
                                                 ?, ?, ?)");


                     $stmt->execute([$Invoice_,
                                      $Invoiced_By,
                                      $Sold_By,
                                      $Product_SKU,
                                      $Sold_On,
                                      $Customer,
                                      $Tracking_,
                                      $Contract_,
                                      $Product_Name,
                                      $Selling_Price,
                                      $District]);
                     $stmt = null;

                }
            }

            // Close opened CSV file
            fclose($csvFile);

            $qstring = '?status=succ';
        }else{
            $qstring = '?status=err';
        }
    }else{
        $qstring = '?status=invalid_file';
    }
}

include('update.php');


// Redirect to the index page
#header("Location: index.php".$qstring);
```

The cron will run this file every morning and process the newly uploaded file that is named activation.csv.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

This is the correct way to write this.

```
<?php

include_once 'connect.php';

    $csvMimes = array('text/x-comma-separated-values', 'text/comma-separated-values', 'application/octet-stream', 'application/vnd.ms-excel', 'application/x-csv', 'text/x-csv', 'text/csv', 'application/csv', 'application/excel', 'application/vnd.msexcel', 'text/plain');

        if(file_exists('dpexpect.csv')){   // Added the file name here

            $csvFile = fopen('dpexpect.csv', 'r');  // Open the CSV for processing. 

            fgetcsv($csvFile);
            fgetcsv($csvFile);
            fgetcsv($csvFile);

            while(($line = fgetcsv($csvFile)) !== FALSE){

                $Invoice_      = $line[0];
                $Invoiced_By   = $line[1];
                $Sold_By       = $line[2];
                $Product_SKU   = $line[3];
                $Sold_On       = $line[4];
                $Customer      = $line[5];
                $Tracking_     = $line[6];
                $Contract_     = $line[7];
                $Product_Name  = $line[8];
                $Selling_Price = $line[9];
                $District      = $line[10];

                $prevQuery = "SELECT ID from dp_expected WHERE Contract_  = '".$line[7]."' AND Tracking_ = '".$line[6]."'";
                $prevResult = $pdo->query($prevQuery);

                if($prevResult->num_rows > 0){

                }elseif($Sold_On != ""){

                  $stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO dp_expected (Invoice_, Invoiced_By, Sold_By, Product_SKU, Sold_On, Customer, Tracking_, Contract_, Product_Name, Selling_Price, District)
                                         VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?,
                                                 ?, ?, ?, ?,
                                                 ?, ?, ?)");


                     $stmt->execute([$Invoice_,
                                      $Invoiced_By,
                                      $Sold_By,
                                      $Product_SKU,
                                      $Sold_On,
                                      $Customer,
                                      $Tracking_,
                                      $Contract_,
                                      $Product_Name,
                                      $Selling_Price,
                                      $District]);
                     $stmt = null;

                }
            }

            // Close opened CSV file
            fclose($csvFile);

            $qstring = '?status=succ';
            Echo "Success";
        }else{
            $qstring = '?status=err';
            echo "error";
        }




include('update.php');


// Redirect to the index page
header("Location: index.php".$qstring);
```

Comment: What *did* you do exactly?

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner I clearly stated what i did within the script.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just declare a file path and use it instead of $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'] for fopen(). Of course, remove all about $_FILES, I mean these checks will go out:

```
if(!empty($_FILES['file']['name']) && in_array($_FILES['file']['type'], $csvMimes)){

    if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'])){
```

You can add other checks, for example if file exists.

Comment: Like this? ```$file = 'dpexpected.csv'

    $csvMimes = array('text/x-comma-separated-values', 'text/comma-separated-values', 'application/octet-stream', 'application/vnd.ms-excel', 'application/x-csv', 'text/x-csv', 'text/csv', 'application/csv', 'application/excel', 'application/vnd.msexcel', 'text/plain');

    if(!empty($file) && in_array($file, $csvMimes)){

        if(file_exists($file)){

            $csvFile = fopen($file, 'r');```

Comment: Near, just remove the mime check, I mean in_array($file, $csvMimes)